# Авторизация VK(api) на java

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу приложение для вк, застрял на этапе авторизации.

---

Отправляю запрос по адресу:

```
url = new URL("https://oauth.vk.com/"+
                    "authorize?client_id=5622141&"+
                    "display=page&"+
                    "redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&"+
                    "scope=friends&response_type=token&"+
                    "v=5.57&"+
                    "state=123456");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

Затем получаю ответ:

```
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {result.append(line);}
```

В result был записан редирект на страницу авторизации откуда мне нужно было вытащить 2 значения: *String ip_h, to_h;*

---

Затем снова делаю запрос с полученными ip_h и to_h и туда же еще вставил свой логин и пароль от вк:

```
URL url2 = new URL("https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1"+
                    "&q=1"+
                    "&ip_h="+ip_h+
                    "&from_host=oauth.vk.com"+
                    "&to="+to_h+
                    "&expire=0"+
                    "&email="+email+
                    "&pass="+password
            );
```

В ответ приходит редирект мол: "Не верно введен пароль или логин". 
Пароль уже меня, пытался использовать другую страницу...проблема осталась.